# Como passar parâmetros pela URL no WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Tenho uma página de eventos no WordPress com a seguinte estrutura de URL `http://exemplo.com.br/eventos`.

Gostaria de passar os seguintes parâmetros, `exemplo.com.br/eventos/ano/mês`, para listar os eventos do mês e ano.
Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Usas alguna regla con un .htaccess ?

Comment: Não, não tentei com nenhum regra no htaccess ainda

Comment: Podrías tratar pasando los valores por get...de la forma http://exemplo.com.br/eventos?ano="2014"&mes="Enero"

Comment: Rober Rozas, gostaria de fazer direto na url, sem ser via GET, sabe algum método de fazer isso?

Comment: Lee la siguiente documentación: http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/

Comment: Funcionou!! Muito obrigado Robert Rozas.

Comment: Excelente Leandro ;)

Answer (score 1):

Rapaz, nativamente, já funciona assim a listagem dos Archives.
Por exemplo, quero ver os posts de junho de 2013 do não Salvo:

```
http://www.naosalvo.com.br/2013/06/
```

Answer (score 1):

## [WP-Router](https://github.com/jbrinley/WP-Router)

O que você precisa é criar rotas específicas, esse plugin auxilia nessa tarefa.

Você pode criar suas rotas e depois recuperar em alguma página específica, exemplo:

Sempre que o o usuário entrar em `site.com/eventos/2013/abril` você pode direcionar ele para o arquivo `eventos.php` e tratar da forma que desejar, os parâmetros estarão disponíveis na variável global `$_GET`.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode acrescentar algo como isso no seu *functions.php*.

```
<?php

    function add_my_var($public_query_vars) {

        $public_query_vars[] = "var_name";

        return $public_query_vars;

    }

    add_filter("query_vars", "add_my_var");

    function do_rewrite() {

        add_rewrite_rule("^page-name/([^/]+)/?$", "index.php?pagename=page-name&var_name=\$matches[1]", 'top');

    }

    add_action("init", "do_rewrite");

?>
```

Neste caso a URL seria próxima disto: `http://example.com/page-name/my-param`

Para recuperar o valor passado você pode tanto usar `get_query_var("var_name")` quanto pode pegar de forma nativa: `$_GET["var_name"]`

Answer (score 1):

Interessante exercício. E seguindo a [dica](http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/) do [Robert Rozas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6358/como-passar-parametros-pela-url-no-wordpress#comment10478_6358) (muchas gracias!) cheguei ao seguinte código (ver comentários para instruções detalhadas de uso e outras explicações).

Em linhas gerais, é só copiar o código num arquivo PHP e colocá-lo na pasta `/wp-content/plugins.php`. Uma vez ativado, é necessário atualizar os Links Permanentes. Depois disso, criar um *page-template* para a página Eventos e utilizar o exemplo descrito no **Modo de Uso**.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Ano e mês para a página Eventos
 * Plugin URI:  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8957/201
 * Description: Adiciona as query vars /ano/mes/ à URL da página Eventos. Escrito com base no artigo publicado no blog rlmseo.com 
 * Author:      brasofilo
 * License:     GPLv3

 MODO DE USO 
 - Após ativar o plugin, atualize a configuração de Links Permanentes, 
   visitando /wp-admin/options-permalink.php e clicando em "Salvar alterações"
 - Crie um Template para a página "Eventos" 
   e certifique-se que o slug da página é "eventos", ie, exemplo.com/eventos
 - Na page template (page-eventos.php) do theme, utilize
        if( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['ano'] ) && isset( $wp_query->query_vars['mes'] ) ) 
        {
            $ano = urldecode( $wp_query->query_vars['ano'] );
            $mes = urldecode( $wp_query->query_vars['mes'] );
            printf( '<h2>Ano: %s</h2>', $ano );
            printf( '<h2>Mes: %s</h2>', $mes );
        }
        // ou use $ano = get_query_var('ano');
 - Visite a página Eventos no site usando a URL exemplo.com/eventos/teste-ano/teste-mes/
 - Agora é só usar as variáveis que vieram da URL, $ano e $mes
 */

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars' );
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules' );

/**
 * Adiciona 'ano' e 'mes' à lista de query vars registradas
 *
 * @param     $vars array
 * @return    array
 */
function add_query_vars( $vars ) 
{
    array_push( $vars, 'ano', 'mes' );
    return $vars;
}

/**
 * Adiciona a regra de rewrite ao banco de dados
 *
 * @param     $rules array
 * @return    array
 */
function add_rewrite_rules( $rules ) 
{
    $new_rules = array_merge( $rules, array( 
        'eventos/(.+?)/(.+?)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=eventos&ano=$matches[1]&mes=$matches[2]' 
    ));
    return $new_rules;
}
```

> Outra implementação pode ser vista em [Receber um parâmetro através de uma URL amigável em uma página do Wordpress](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/204365/201)

<sub>Porque usar um plugin? Vide: [**Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031)</sub>