# Receber um parâmetro através de uma URL amigável em uma página do Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, url-amigável

Eu tenho uma página Wordpress chamada ***Recordings*** que é acessada através de http://localhost/recordings e preciso passar um parâmetro ID no final da URL que seja possível usar posteriormente pra criar um conteúdo dinâmico na página Wordpress. Exemplo: http://localhost/recordings/123, e via PHP pegar a ID **123**.

OBS: Precisar ser via URL amigavel e não via querystring (recordings/?id=123).

Como fazer isso? Qual a melhor pratica e padrão Wordpress para essa finalidade?

Comment: Acabo de me dar conta que já tinha respondido uma pergunta similar... como o código é ligeiramente diferente vou deixar a resposta abaixo em vez de deletar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deve usar um *endpoint* através da função [**`add_rewrite_endpoint()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_endpoint/):

```
# conferir outras possibilidades além do EP_ALL na documentação
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'recordings', EP_ALL );
```

O *endpoint* deve ser adicionado nas `query_vars`:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $vars ){
    $vars[] = 'recordings';
    return $vars;
});
```

A partir daí, pode-se conferir qualquer URL do site:

```
# Exemplo de URL: http://example.com/post-name/recordings/Nome do Disco/
$recordings = get_query_var( 'recordings','' );
# $recordings vai ser igual a "Nome do Disco"
```

O `add_rewrite_endpoint` só precisa ser chamado uma vez e deve-se fazer um *refresh* dos permalinks. Traduzido num plugin fica assim:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Adicionar Custom Endpoint
 * Plugin URI:  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/204365/201
 * Author: brasofilo
 */

register_activation_hook(   __FILE__, array( 'SOPT_Endpoint', 'activation' ) );

add_action( 'plugins_loaded',  array ( SOPT_Endpoint::get_instance(), 'plugin_setup' ) );

class SOPT_Endpoint {
    /**
     * Plugin instance.
     */
    protected static $instance = NULL;

    /**
     * Constructor. Intentionally left empty and public.
     */
    public function __construct() {}    

    /**
     * Access this plugin’s working instance
     */
    public static function get_instance(){
        NULL === self::$instance and self::$instance = new self;
        return self::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * Refresh permalinks on plugin activation
     * Source: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/108517/12615 
     */
    public static function activation(){
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) )
            return;

        $plugin = isset( $_REQUEST['plugin'] ) ? $_REQUEST['plugin'] : '';
        check_admin_referer( "activate-plugin_{$plugin}" );

        #source: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/118694/12615
        add_rewrite_endpoint( 'recordings', EP_ALL ); 
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }

    /**
     * Inicio do plugin
     */
    public function plugin_setup(){
        add_filter( 'query_vars', array( $this, 'query_vars' ) );
        # Só para demonstrar o plugin funcionando
        add_action( 'wp_footer', array( $this, 'wp_footer' ) );
    }

    public function query_vars( $vars ){
        $vars[] = 'recordings';
        return $vars;       
    }

    # Função para demonstrar como capturar o endpoint
    # - visitar qualquer URL do site e acrescentar /recordings/VARIAVEL
    # - - conferir o rodapé da página para ver o resultado
    public function wp_footer(){
        $recordings = get_query_var( 'recordings','' );
        if( '' === $recordings ) {
            echo '<h1 style="font-size:4em">Endpoint sem variável.</h1>';
        } 
        else {
            printf( '<h1 style="font-size:4em">Variável do endpoint: %s</h1>', urldecode( $recordings ) );
        }
    }
}
```