# Chamar outra página com o action de um form

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress

Tenho este código para abrir vários formulários na mesma página:

```
<select id="mudar_produto"> 
    <option value="#produto_1">Novo Produto Higiene</option> 
    <option value="#produto_2">Entrada de Produtos Higiene</option> 
    <option value="#produto_3">Novo Produto Nutricia</option> 
</select> 

<section class="hide-section" id="produto_1">
    <form id="form3" method="POST" onsubmit="return form_validation()"> 
        <fieldset> 
            <h1>
                <legend>
                    <center>
                        <strong>Produtos de Higiene</strong>
            </center>
        </h1><br> 
        <fieldset class="grupo">
    <div class="campo">
            <strong><label for="Nome do Produto">Nome do Produto</label></strong> 
            <input type="text" id="DescricaoProd" name="DescricaoProd" required="" style="width:350px">
        </div>
    <div class="campo"> 
        <strong><label for="Unidade">Unidade</label></strong> 
            <input type="text" id="DescricaoUnid" name="DescricaoUnid" style="width:160px" required="" size="120">
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="botao submit">Registo</button>
    </form> 
</section>

<section class="hide-section" id="produto_2"> 
    <form name="form4" method="POST" onsubmit="return form_validation()"> 
         <fieldset> 
            <h1>
                <legend>
                    <center>
                        <strong>Entrada de Produtos de Higiene</strong>
            </center>
        </h1><br>       
        <fieldset class="grupo">
    <div class="campo">
            <strong><label for="Data Entrada">Data Entrada</label></strong>
            <input id="DataEntrada" type="date" name="DataEntrada" required="" style="width:180px" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>">
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="grupo">
    <div class="campo"> 
        <strong><label for="Produto">Produto</label></strong>
        <select id="first_dd" name="Produto" style="width:250px" required> 
            <option></option> 
            <?php 
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM centrodb.ProdHigieneteste WHERE Ativo = 1 ORDER BY DescricaoProd ASC"; 
                $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
                while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){ 
                    echo '<option value="'.$ln['IDProd'].'"> '.$ln['DescricaoProd'].'</option>'; 
                    $valencia[$ln['IDProd']]=array('DescricaoUnid'=>$ln['DescricaoUnid'],'DescricaoUnid'=>$ln['DescricaoUnid']); 
                } 
            ?> 
        </select> 
        </div>
    <div class="campo"> 
        <strong><label for="Unidade">Unidade</label></strong>
        <select id="second_dd" name="Unid" style="width:150px" required> 
            <option></option> 
            <?php
                foreach ($valencia as $key => $value) { 
                    echo '<option data-id="'.$key.'" value="'.$value['DescricaoUnid'].'">'.$value['DescricaoUnid'].'</option>'; 
                }
            ?> 
        </select><br> 
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="grupo">
    <div class="campo"> 
        <strong><label for="Quantidade">Quantidade</label></strong>
            <input type="text" id="Quantidade" name="Quantidade" style="width:80px" required="" size="40">
        </div>
    <div class="campo"> 
        <strong><label for="Preço">Preço</label></strong>
            <input type="text" id="Preco" name="Preco" style="width:100px" value="0.00">
        </div> 
    </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" name="submit1" class="botao submit">Registo</button>
    </form>
</section>   

<section class="hide-section" id="produto_3"> 
    <form id="form3" name="form3" method="POST" onsubmit="return form_validation()" > 
        <fieldset> 
            <h1>
                <legend>
                    <center>
                        <strong>Produtos de Nutricia</strong>
            </center>
        </h1><br> 
        <fieldset class="grupo">
    <div class="campo">
            <strong><label for="Nome do Produto">Nome do Produto</label></strong>
                <input type="text" id="ProdNutricia" name="ProdNutricia" style="width:350px" required="" size="120" />
            </div> 
    </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" name="submit2" class="botao submit">Registo</button>
    </form> 
</section>
```

Tenho esta função para mudar de formulário:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".hide-section:not(:first)").hide();
    $('#mudar_produto').change(function(){
        $('.hide-section').hide();
        $($(this).val()).show();
    });
    $('#first_dd').change(function(){ 
        var id = $('#first_dd option:selected').val(); 
        $.each($('#second_dd option'),function(){ 
            if($(this).attr('data-id')==id){ 
                $(this).attr('selected',true); 
            }
        }); 
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Agora pretendo em cada formulário colocar o action para enviar para outra página para inserir na tabela da base de dados, exemplo:

```
<form id="form3" method="POST" action="\\xxx.xxx.x.xx\kitchen\wordpress\wp-content\themes\busiprof\teste2.php" onsubmit="return form_validation()">
```

Na página teste2 tenho o seguinte código para testar se está a enviar:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    print_r($_POST);
}
?>
```

Mas quando clico no botão de registo dá este erro na consola do google chrome:

```
POST http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/kitchen/wordpress/wp-content/themes/busiprof/teste2.php 404 (Not Found)
```

Estou a trabalhar com o apache, php 7.0 e wordpress.

Comment: Pelo erro parece não estar encontrando essa teste2.php nesta pasta.

Comment: mas esse teste2.php está dentro dessa pasta

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema não colocando o .php no final do caminho, ficou assim: `action="./teste2"`. Se colocar o .php não funciona

Comment: Wordpress é um caso à parte. Você precisa pesquisar como enviar parâmetros para a consulta. Aqui tem uma boa ajuda sobre esse assunto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6358/como-passar-parâmetros-pela-url-no-wordpress. O segredo das requisições está em: 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';

Answer (score -2):

Cara, o ideal é você colocar o caminho a partir do arquivo que você está editando e não a partir da raiz!

ou seja, se tiver pastas atrás, ../../pasta/arquivo.php
se estiver na mesma pasta, arquivo.php.

não precisa desse hrefzão!

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) mas, até lá, escreva apenas resposta que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/220842)

Comment: Mas responde! Acima, ele respondeu que o arquivo está dentro da pasta. Estou dizendo que é só referenciar dentro da própria pasta ao invés da raiz